# How to change body opacity while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, opacity

I want to make an opacity on all my elements except #header while someone is scrolling on my site. Directly while scroll is stopped, it should fadein with full opacity again.

So if someone scroll, opacity should be like 0.5 and if the visitor stops scrolling the opacity should turn back to 1.

I have a fixed header that follow the site when scrolling so the best thing would be if just my element #header isn't affected by this.

Comment: Show us some code you've already tried.

Comment: Have you tried searching the jQuery documentation for [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and [fade](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some jQuery can handle this for you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    (function() {
        var timer;
        $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('yourElem').addClass('is-scrolling');
            // time before scrolling is registered as stopped
            timer = setTimeout( refresh , 500 );
        });
        var refresh = function () { 
            $('yourElem').removeClass('is-scrolling');
        };
    })();
});
```

Then just throw some CSS on the page

```
.is-scrolling {
  opacity: 0;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks! Just one question, when the scroll is done I think the opacity just comes back. I would prefer a fade in from 0.5 to 1.0

Comment: Whoops. Put the transition on whatever element gets the class added to it, not the .is-scrolling class

Comment: Hi! I managed to do that, sorry for my quick respond without trying. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.fade').each(function() {
        var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

        if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { (scrolling down)
            if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
        } else {  (scrolling up)
            if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
        }
    });
```